# SQL query embedded in python script - ERROR

Tags: python, mysql, csv, python-2.7, mysql-python

I wanted a script that iterates through csv files in a folder and dump them into a MySQL database. I was able to dump one csv file into it.. But have troubles passing the file name in to the SQL script.

This is the code I use

```
file_path="C:\csv-files"
files=os.listdir(file_path)
files.sort()
for n in files:

    cursor.execute(" LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '%s' INTO TABLE new_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' Lines terminated by '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES ",(n))
```

And I get the following error

```
raise errorclass, errorvalue
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'file1.csv'' INTO TABLE new_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY' at line 1")
```

If I use the file name directly instead of passing it, it works fine.

If you can see in the error thrown out, there seems to be an error in the SQL Script.

This would be the whole code

```
import csv
import MySQLdb
import sys
import os
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='password',
    db='some_db')


cursor = connection.cursor()

file_path="C:\csv-files"
files=os.listdir(file_path)
files.sort()
for n in files:
    print n



    cursor.execute(" LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE %s INTO TABLE new_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' Lines terminated by '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES " %n)



connection.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, replace '%s' with %s in the query. MySQLdb handles any quoting automatically.

Here's the code with some corrections and changes:

```
import MySQLdb
import os

CSV_DIR = "C:\csv-files"

connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             passwd='password',
                             db='some_db',
                             local_infile=1)

cursor = connection.cursor()

try:
    for filename in sorted(os.listdir(CSV_DIR)):
        cursor.execute("""LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE %s
                          INTO TABLE new_table
                          FIELDS
                          TERMINATED BY ','
                          OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
                          ESCAPED BY '"'
                          LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                          IGNORE 1 LINES""",
                      (os.path.join(CSV_DIR, filename),))

    connection.commit()
finally:
    cursor.close()
```

NOTE: I set local_infile parameter to 1 in MySQLdb.connect and pass filename in tuple to execute.

Works for me.